# android Action_send intent how to know once an email has been sent to close the current activity?

Tags: android

I have an action_send intent that allows the user to send an email however when they are done I would like to return them to a different activity than they were on when the email was sent.
My intent code is below :

```
public void sendEmail(){
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + "screenshots/";
    String target_filename = "CheeseNav.jpg";
    File externalFile = new File(path, target_filename);

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("text/plain");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{""});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email sent from android app");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
    Uri sendUri = Uri.fromFile(externalFile);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, sendUri);

    try{
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,  "Send mail..."));
    } catch(android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){
        Toast.makeText(ScreenViewer.this, "There are no email clients installed.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return to some activity had before the process to send the email you have to make an intent with flags to clear the top of the activities. You can use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```